# Problem in request C# ASP.NET Core Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger

I have a problem. I have three tables: Persons, Skills, PersonsSkills. PersonsSkills - an intermediate table. I want to write only id there, but I get an error that the body of Skills and Persons is empty. How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

[Person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xxdu.jpg)

[Skill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QMgv.jpg)

[PersonSkill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ympC4.jpg)

[OnModelCreating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiHsX.jpg)

[Swagger Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQpVP.jpg)

[Swagger Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55IlY.jpg)

Comment: Create separate "view" models for your API. The examples you have currently are classes which you should create on the server for interacting with the db. Create a new set of classes with the validation you need from the client and then map them to your data layer

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Instead of passing the `NULL` value, try to change it with any other value. So it would not trigger the validation. See if that way fixes the said error.